# Python : Rendering part of webpage with proper styling from server

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am building a screen clipping app.

So far:

- I can get the html mark up of the part of the web page the user has selected including images and videos.
- I then send them to a server to process the html with BeautifulSoup to sanitize the html and convert all relative paths if any to absolute paths

Now I need to render the part of the page. But I have no way to render the styling. Is there any library to help me in this matter or any other way in python ?

One way would be to fetch the whole webpage with urllib2 and remove the parts of the body I don't need and then render it.

But there must be a more pythonic way :)

Note: I don't want a screenshot. I am trying to render proper html with styling.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the complete webpage, extract the `style` elements and the stylesheet `link` elements and download the files referenced the latter. That should give you the CSS used on the page.

Comment: Thanks :) just finished doing the same.